# Mouse over Effect on a picture through CSS, with changed background and Text

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to achieve the effect of mouse over on a picture which dims it's background and brings over a text on top.

As an e.g. you can visit [this](http://www.whitehouseblackmarket.com/store/home.jsp) page and scroll down a little to see the second set of two pictures. When you mouseover them, they become darker and bring up the text.

One of the things that came in mind was to change the picture with mouseover but that's an overkill. I am hoping to achieve it through CSS.

### HTML

```
<div id="bottomWide">           
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="http://127.0.0.1/www/media/wysiwyg/sub-head1.jpg" alt=""> 
                                <div>Some text here, style as needed</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://127.0.0.1/www/media/wysiwyg/sub-head1.jpg" alt="">
                                <div>Some text here, style as needed</div> 
        </li>

    </ul> 
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#bottomWide{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;


}

#bottomWide ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    /* For Mouse Over*/
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#bottomWide li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
    text-align:justify;
    float: left;
}

#bottomWide img{
    width:100%;
}



#bottomWide li div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* 100% will equal the dimensions of the image, as nothing else will be inside the .container */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    /* This will create the fade effect */
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    /* Include all required vendor prefixes for opacity and transition */
}

#bottomWide li div:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is

- Have an absolutely positioned div on top of the image that has an opacity of 0 by default, with a dark background. This contains your text. You could also make it show/hide with `display: none` and `display: block`, but this way you wouldn't be able to add the fade in / fade out effect, as CSS transitions don't support the display property.
- On hover, increase the opacity to almost 1.
- Include a CSS transition for the opacity property to make it look like the background is fading in.

See http://jsfiddle.net/AEyW3/

Comment: Hi, Your fix works but with a small gripe. I have two pictures within LI and when I mouseover, it just highlights both the pictures when it should be doing the one I moused-over on. I updated my CSS and HTML.

Comment: The problem is that the `div`s are positioned absolutely in relation to your `ul` element, when they are actually inside `li` elements. As a result, both `div`s are as wide as the `ul` and appear on top of each other, not on top of their respective images. The elements in relation to which other elements are positioned absolutely are specified with the `position: relative` rule -- in your case just remove it from your `ul` and add it to your `li`s.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an opacity animation and a text display value in css

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/4Dfpm/360/

```
div:hover img {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: You basically posted the same answer as me

Comment: @Cody So? What's your point. This happens all the time on StackOverflow

Comment: @Cody No i didn't. A) it's a very very basic opacity CSS, only one way to do it. It is elementary level coding, nothing unique here at all. B) you did not show the text appearing as the OP clearly asked.

Comment: Hi Guys, Your solution works fine but within my scenario where I use LI, the mouseover just darkens both of my LIs. I have two LIs which have an Image respectively. Updated the HTML/CSS in my question.

Answer (score 1):

They are most likely using the `opacity` property. All images have a default opacity of `1`, so if you decrease it, to say `.5`, it will appear to darken the image.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Dfpm/)